# Problems with MySQL autoincrement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL Database with InnoDB and working with MySQL Workbench. Even though I've set auto_increment to 1, it always increases by 3. So I've got a row with a value 1, the next with 4, the next with 7. When I delete row 7 and after that, I put a new row into the table, the value is 10, not 7 again.
Anybody an idea why my database behaves so? How can I change this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check your table schema, identity specification(identity increment).

Comment: This is not specific.. mysql or sql.. It's different.. update your tagging options

Answer (score 2):

You can change autoincrement value in mysql workbench.

see below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Well, if I change this value it doesn't have any affect. Also it automaticly changes each time I add a row

Answer (score 1):

its normal (default behavior) for increment to keeping counting up, even if you delete a row. Can you show your code?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html